# Different LIKE behaviour between my application and the Access query wizard

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I am executing following query from my web application and access 2007 query wizard. And I am getting two different result.

```
SELECT R.Rept_Name, D.Dist_Name,S.State_Name FROM (tblReporter AS R LEFT JOIN tblDist AS D ON R.Dist_Id=D.Dist_Id) LEFT JOIN  tblState AS S ON S.State_Id=R.State_Id WHERE R.Rept_Name LIKE '*Ra*' ORDER BY R.Rept_Name;
```

Result from web application is with 0 rows and from query wizard 2 rows.If I remove where condition than both result are same. Please help me what is wrong with query. If any other info require please tell me.

Web application code ...

```
public DataTable getRept(string rept, string mobno)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(getConnection()))
    {
        using (OleDbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT R.Rept_Name, D.Dist_Name,S.State_Name FROM (tblReporter AS R LEFT JOIN tblDist AS D ON R.Dist_Id=D.Dist_Id) LEFT JOIN  tblState AS S ON S.State_Id=R.State_Id WHERE R.Rept_Name LIKE '*" + rept + "*'  ORDER BY R.Rept_Name;";
            conn.Open();
            using (OleDbDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (sdr.HasRows)
                    dt.Load(sdr);
            }

        }
    }
    return dt;
}
```

Comment: PLEASE quit using inline text.  You are wide open to SQL injenction.  Please use parameters for every query - even if you are just providing this as an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting tripped up by the difference in LIKE wildcard characters between queries run in Access itself and queries run from an external application.

When running a query from within Access itself you need to use the asterisk as the wildcard character: `LIKE '*Ra*'`.

When running a query from an external application (like your C# app) you need to use the percent sign as the wildcard character: `LIKE '%Ra%'`.

Comment: Sir how I can use parametrized query in like operator. like ' LIKE '%@Ra%' '. this didn't work.What is correct syntax.

Comment: @AnilLimbani Your query should use `... LIKE ? ...` and you'll need to do a `setString(1, "%Ra%")` on your `PreparedStatement` object. If you need more help with this please [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).