# Dataset Retuns 0 records but same query returns multiple records when executed in access 2013

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, ms-access-2013, crystal-reports-2010

**I use back-end as MS Access 2013 , when i execute function it returns 0 in a messagebox but i execute the same query in access 2013 in sql mode it returns multiple rows.problem is why this function retuns 0 rows in dataset table.It should return some rows**

**Tables**

bills(bill_id,m_id,dated,ownername,oldvalue,newvalue,units,oth,rcharges,billamount)

meters(m_id,m_type,ownername,flatno,designation,qualification,department)

```
Private Sub frmViewStatementReport_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim Billrpt As New RptBillStatement
        Billrpt.Load(Application.StartupPath & "\RptBillStatement.rpt")
        Try
            Dim qry As String
            ' I have Tried the above both queries but returns 0 rows in table(0).

            qry = "SELECT bills.ownername as Name, meters.designation as des,   meters.department as depart, bills.billAmount as amount FROM bills LEFT JOIN meters ON meters.m_id =bills.m_id  WHERE bills.dated like '*-jan-*'"

            'qry = "SELECT bt.bill_id,bt.ownername as Name, mt.designation as designation, mt.department as department,bt.billAmount as billAmount FROM bills AS bt INNER JOIN meters AS mt ON bt.m_id = mt.m_id WHERE bt.dated like '*-jan-*'"          

            Using conn = New OleDbConnection(ConString)
                Using daa As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(qry, conn)
                    Using dss As DataSet = New DataSet
                        conn.Open()
                        daa.Fill(dss, "Bills")  
                         Dim dt As New DataTable
                        dt = ds.Tables(0)
                        Billrpt.SetDataSource(ds.Tables(0))
                        Me.CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()
                        Me.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource =Billrpt 

                        MsgBox(dss.Tables(0).Rows.Count.ToString)
                        conn.Close()
                    End Using
                End Using
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception            
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)                 
        End Try
 End Sub
```

Comment: The wild card is nearly always % outside MS Access. It is only % running in an MS Access query (DAO)

Comment: Thanks Fionnuala for giving solution to my Problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Different result from same query executed by my application and by Access 2007 query wizard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21161801/different-result-from-same-query-executed-by-my-application-and-by-access-2007-q)

Comment: Of course I meant  It is only * running in an MS Access query (DAO)

Answer (score 0):

The wildcard character is actually '%%' with the Like Clause instead of '**'

```
WHERE bills.dated like '%-jan-%'"
```

Should solve your problem.